# Google Chrome autocomplete not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I get the autocomplete suggestions when I type, but when I select the value it doesn't populate the field.

Here is a GIF to illustrate the issue.
https://media.giphy.com/media/lzwkRcCKiLafkRcjEE/giphy.gif

Here is another example of it working, then stopping to work:

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="last-name" autocomplete="last-name" value="MacIsaac">
```

The form is built with React

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocomplete, `autocomplete="family-name"` should autocomplete to the last name.

So the end result should be: `<input type="text" name="last-name" autocomplete="family-name" value="MacIsaac">`

Comment: The gif shows that auto complete is prompting. What's not happening is any of the other correct behaviours. Here's a GIF with your changes,
https://media.giphy.com/media/2xExfjv9j1beSZ8VLf/giphy.gif

Comment: @SeanJM Have you tried debugging in any other browsers?

Comment: I think the issue is something with React. I have `shouldComponentUpdate` working correctly where it's static, I put the same code JSFiddle and it's fine. This is probably just something I'm missing.

Comment: I've been able to recreate the behavior on Chrome here with a basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/1rjL506k/2/

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your inputs are wrapped in a `form` element and autocomplete will work.